# Why value is not autogenerated?

Tags: postgresql

I have column defined as:

```
not null default uuid_generate_v4()
```

when I try to insert `NULL` value I get error:

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  null value in column "uuid" violates not-null constraint
```

The code:

```
        INSERT INTO files( uuid, storage, type, user_id, extra )
        VALUES( ?,?,?,?,? )
        ON CONFLICT( uuid ) DO UPDATE SET
           storage = EXCLUDED.storage,
           type    = EXCLUDED.type,
           user_id = EXCLUDED.user_id,
           extra   = EXCLUDED.extra
        RETURNING *
      SQL
      ,$self->{ uuid }
      ,$self->storage .""
      ,ref $self
      ,$self->{ owner_id }
      ,JSON::XS->new->allow_nonref->encode( $args{ extra } // {} )
```

I am confused.
How to create new row, if `$self->{ uuid }` is not defined yet. And how to update record, if `$self->{ uuid }` was provided

Comment: If the column is autogenerated you don't need to add it on the insert column listing, just put those that you are manually informing.

Comment: If you want the `default` to kick in, remove the `uuid` column from the target list - but then you will never get a conflict anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: is there a way to make `UPDATE OR INSERT` in my case?

Comment: If you generate a new unique ID during insert then what would you want to update? There won't be another row with the same ID.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It seems I should split this query by two and check `$self->{ uuid }` in application

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is different to `DEFAULT`

If you say the `uuid` is NULL then db wont try to use DEFAULT value.

You must omit the `uuid` field so DB use the DEFAULT

```
INSERT INTO files( storage, type, user_id, extra )
```

Comment: `You must omit the uuid`: and I lose ability to `UPDATE OR INSERT`

Comment: Create a working sample in [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) so I can try and fix it.